# Is this PHP email validation comprehensive and complete?

Tags: php

It might be a bit redundant, and I'm not experienced enough to wrap it all into one function. But,
I'm aiming for unicode email adresses and a quick loose but secure validation. How can I improve this?

note: I'm using PDO, so I'm mainly focusing on preventing HTML injection. Is this an issue ether way if I'm outputting user input in htmlspecialchars?

```
$email = "<strong>Bàt mâ'n</strong>@çupærman.dc";

function isValid($email) {
    return !preg_match('/[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[^ ]{2,7}/', $email);
}

$encoded_email = htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
if (isValid($email)) {
    echo $encoded_email. " is not valid!";
} else {
    if ($encoded_email===$email) {
    echo $encoded_email. " is valid!";
    } else {
        echo $encoded_email. " is not valid!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use filters

You are a lot better off just using the built in [validation filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php):

```
$email_a = 'joe@example.com';
$email_b = 'bogus';

if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This (email_a) email address is considered valid.";
}
if (filter_var($email_b, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This (email_b) email address is considered valid.";
}
```

### Handling International email addresses

International domain names are not really UTF-8 - they are [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encoded strings (ascii). A UTF-8 local name isn't considered valid by most servers - i.e.

- foo@çupærman.dc valid (after converting the domain to punycode)
- foo@xn--uprman-quaf.dc valid (this is the above puny code converted)
- çupærman@foo.dc INvalid

if you just want to prevent injection - run the email address through striptags before processing; you could also follow [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5219848/761202) and use loose validation and simply send a mail to confirm the mail exists.

Comment: Completely forgot about filter_var(). Great point made, hopefully OP will see this.

Comment: I'll be going with this solution, and I'll be confirming the email as well to prevent impersonation and doing front end validation for better user experience. I actually looked into the filters before making this post but wasn't happy with the unicode handling on the first email part, but at this point it just make more sense to use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$email = "<strong>Bàt mâ'n</strong>@çupærman.dc";

function validateEmail($email){
    $encoded_email = htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $is_valid = !preg_match('/[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[^ ]{2,7}/', $email);

    if( $is_valid || $encoded_email === $email ) $end = " is ";
    else $end = " is not ";

    return $encoded_email . $end . " valid.";
}
```

I absconded the preg_match() to return within the function INTO a variable - as it is less expensive than a function call within a function call (however, if you're doing more than just a preg_match() to validate, then revert it back to the isValid() function.

I also reworked your if/else/if/else into an (if|if)/else statement - higher readability and saves you one else call.

Also, I put your code into a function and made it return once, rather than echo three times.

Comment: Superb! Tanks, I'm really new to all of this, and a graphics designer so it's not even my mindset. Helped out quite a bit. Naturally I've also implemented email validation by sending a confirmation link.

Comment: Also see AD7six's answer below, I completely forgot about the filter_var() func.